# Counterexample of subsequential limits forming a closed subset

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here I am reading the book "Principle of mathematical analysis", on page 52

**Note** that the Subsequential limit is the limit of a subsequence.

**Theorem 3.7**: The subsequential limits of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ form a closed subset of $X$.

However, I found a counterexample and didn't understand a part of the proof in the book. I am going to copy the proof here:

**Proof from Rudin - Principle of mathematical analysis**

Let $E^*$ be the set of all subsequential limits of $\{p_n\}$ and let $q$ be a limit point of $E^*$. We have to show that $q\in E^*$.

Choose $n_1$ such that $p_{n_1}\neq q$. (If no such $n_1$ exists, then $E^*$ has only one point, and there is nothing to prove.) Put $\delta =d(q,p_{n_1})$. Suppose $n_1 ,...,n_{i-1}$ are chosen. Since $q$ is a limit point of $E^*$, there is an $x\in E^*$ with $d(x,q)<\frac{\delta}{2^i}$.  Since $x\in E^*$, there is an $n_1 >n_{i-1}$ such that $d(x,p_{n_i})<\frac{\delta}{2^i}$. Thus $$d(q,p_{n_i})<2^{1-i}\delta$$

for all $i$. $\color{red}{\text{This says that } \{p_{n_i}\} \text{ converges to } q \text{. Hence } q\in E^*}$.

,

(1). I do not understand the red part, why does $p_{n_i}$ converging to $q$ imply that $q\in E^*$

**Counterexample**

consider the sequence $(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Enumerated as: $$\Big\{1+1, 1+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+1,\frac{1}{3}+1 ,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, 1+\frac{1}{3}, 1+\frac{1}{4}...\Big\}$$

This is a valid subsequence of the original sequence. Visually, can be constructed by writing the double array of sequence as the following

$$
\begin{matrix}
1+1 & 1+\frac{1}{2} & 1+\frac{1}{3} & 1+\frac{1}{4} & \dots\\
\frac{1}{2}+1 & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{3}+1 & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4}+1 & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4} \\
\vdots & & & & \ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

Start with $1+1$, go left once, then left-down diagonal until you hit the boundary, go down once, then go right-up diagonal until you hit the boundary. and repeat.

,

This sequence has subsequential limit $\Big\{\frac{1}{m}\Big\} =\Big\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\Big\}$. However, this set has a limit point $0$ which is NOT in the set. Thus giving a non-closed set.

(2). What's wrong with this counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the definition of your sequence $\big\{\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{n} \big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $, it seems you are trying to define essentially a 2d-array, this is not a sequence, a sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to some other set, you have defined a function from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For your sequence, the set of subsequential limits is $$\{0\}\cup\{\tfrac{1}{m}:m=1,2,\ldots\}.$$ I am not sure why you think $0$ is not a subsequential limit, but note that a subsequence like $(1+1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}, \ldots)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Because I somehow thought that the limit of the sets of sequential limits is not a sequential limit. This answers (2), thanks

Comment: The red part concludes closure because the previous line shows that there is a subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ that converges to $q$. Therefore, $q\in E^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think $p_{n_1} = q$ in the first sentence, second paragraph of the proof might be a typo. It was probably meant to say $p_{n_1} \neq q$.

I misinterpreted your counterexample in my original answer. An explanation is given in the question's comments, by user Sangchul Lee.

About question (1), isn’t it just the definition? $\{p_{n_i}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{p_n\}$, and it has a limit $q$, so $q$ is a subsequential limit of $\{p_n\}$ and is an element of $E^*$.

Comment: Because I somehow thought that the limit of the sets of sequential limits is not a sequential limit. Now both of the my questions are solved, thanks.